# Android Studio not launching emulator

Tags: android, sdk, emulation

When I launch sdk for virtual device android emulator not launched. Installed java and android studio but get stucked, Please help me out.

Here is snapshot of my android studio

Comment: Please add the missing snapshot so we'll be able to help you

Comment: I have 1 reputation when I add it says you required 10 reputations

Comment: upload it to any hosting website and paste a link to it